# What is a good reporting service for a simple database/hobbyist setup?

Tags: language-agnostic, report, reporting

I have a meager production environment running on my PC for a little application that I work on in my spare time. At this point I have the basics setup, MySQL, junit, svn... I am midway through development and I now need to generate various reports (not development/logging/event reports). These reports are based on what data is in the database.

*Now, my question is this*: Is there an existing reporting tool that accepts SQL and generates various reports (via: email, PDF, etc). Some tool which makes writing new reports easy, while also having a somewhat robust set of features. Does this software exist or must I write all of these reports myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports)

Comment: This has a lot of nice features... Can it even send reports via FTP?

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend [myDBR](http://mydbr.com). With this tools you can generate reports in a fast an efficient way. Also adding charts and other external objects (e.g. images, videos) is very simple.

Best of all the tool is available for free (community version).

Answer (score -1):

Possibly you can look into reports developed using R programming also as you can do statistical analysis as well.