# Reportgenerator Java

Tags: java, reporting

I am looking for a **report** generator to embed into a **java** application.

I would like to define the report using some **textual** language (e.g. XML).

The layouts are rather simple (no flows). I want to print out labels with graphics, barcode and texts.

What are my options? Which open source / free generators are available for java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports)) may be the thing you are looking for.
It also open-source, and has plugins for IDEs such as [iReport](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4425/ireport) for NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

[BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/) should be suitable.  It provides a whole system (design engine, reporting engine, chart engine).  The underlying report file format is XML ([example](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/examples/reports/2.1/highlighting/ProductListAfter.rptdesign)).  There is a GUI report designer.

Answer (score 1):

This is repost of the variety of:

[What is a good reporting service for a simple database/hobbyist setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541128/what-is-a-good-reporting-service-for-a-simple-database-hobbyist-setup)

Do a little searching first, there's a lot of opinions. Jasper is my choice, not necessarily the best choice.

Comment: that question is language agnostic, so it is not as useful for a focused comparison of Java libraries.

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic Reports](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/), which uses Jasper Reports, could be a good solution.